# Using Filter(Negate(is.na), x) on a list results in unexpected behaviour

Tags: r

Consider

```
l1 <- list("a", NA, 1:3, NA)
l2 <- list("a", NULL, 1:3, NULL)
```

Why does `Filter(Negate(is.na), l1)` not work, while `Filter(Negate(is.null), l2)` does work as expected (it returns all elements of `l2` which are not `NULL`)?

The helpfile for `?Filter` says

> ...Note that possible NA values are currently always taken as false; control over NA handling may be added in the future.

I still dont really understand the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is.na` returns a vector for each element of the list; you want `anyNA` (or perhaps `exactlyNA` as defined below):

```r
l1 <- list("a", NA, 1:3, NA)
l2 <- list("a", NULL, 1:3, NULL) 
Filter(Negate(is.na), l1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] NA
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
Filter(Negate(anyNA), l1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
exactlyNA <- function(x) identical(x, NA)
Filter(Negate(exactlyNA), l1)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 1 2 3
```

<sup>Created on 2018-11-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Your first example effectively tries to select the 1st, 3rd, 4th, and 5th elements of your list. Nothing to do with `NA`.